# Start the Page Menu not from root_page, rather from second level

Tags: django, content-management-system, wagtail, templatetags

I have a page tree which begins with 3 pages:

```
/private
/business
/education
```

in each of those pages there are several other pages inside.

Like as the wagtail demosite I built a templatetag to implement the top navigation in my base template. the special thing is, that my menu is split in two sections: the first level (private, business, education) is shown up on the top of my website (section menu) and the child elements of those pages lies in my bootstrap navbar (top menu). how can I tell the top_menu model to ignore the first level, because its already shown in my section menu?

**menu_tags.py**

```
from django import template


register = template.Library()


@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_site_root(context):
    return context['request'].site.root_page


def has_menu_children(page):
    return page.get_children().live().in_menu().exists()


@register.inclusion_tag('tags/section_menu.html', takes_context=True)
def section_menu(context, parent, calling_page=None):
    menuitems_section = parent.get_children().filter(
        live=True,
        show_in_menus=True
    )
    return {
        'calling_page': calling_page,
        'menuitems': menuitems_section,
        # required by the pageurl tag that we want to use within this template
        'request': context['request'],
    }


@register.inclusion_tag('tags/top_menu.html', takes_context=True)
def top_menu(context, parent, calling_page=None):
    menuitems = parent.get_children().filter(
        live=True,
        show_in_menus=True
    )
    for menuitem in menuitems:
        menuitem.show_dropdown = has_menu_children(menuitem)
    return {
        'calling_page': calling_page,
        'menuitems': menuitems,
        # required by the pageurl tag that we want to use within this template
        'request': context['request'],
    }


# Retrieves the children of the top menu items for the drop downs
@register.inclusion_tag('tags/top_menu_children.html', takes_context=True)
def top_menu_children(context, parent):
    menuitems_children = parent.get_children()
    menuitems_children = menuitems_children.live().in_menu()
    return {
        'parent': parent,
        'menuitems_children': menuitems_children,
        # required by the pageurl tag that we want to use within this template
        'request': context['request'],
    }
```

**section_menu.html**

```
{% load menu_tags wagtailcore_tags %}

{% for menuitem in menuitems %}
    <li class="{% if calling_page.url == menuitem.url %} active{% endif %}">
        <a href="{% pageurl menuitem %}">{{ menuitem.title }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**top_menu.html**

```
{% load menu_tags wagtailcore_tags %}
{% get_site_root as site_root %}

{% for menuitem in menuitems %}
    <li class="{% if menuitem.show_dropdown %}dropdown{% endif %}{% if menuitem.active %} active{% endif %}">
        {% if menuitem.show_dropdown %}
            <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="#">{{ menuitem.title }} <b class="caret"></b></a>
            {% top_menu_children parent=menuitem %}
        {% else %}
            <a href="{% pageurl menuitem %}">{{ menuitem.title }}</a>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

**header.html (where my section menu lies)**

```
<header class="ms-header ms-header-dark">
    <div class="departement-switcher">
        <div class="container">
            <ul>
                {% block menu %}
                    {% get_site_root as site_root %}
                    {% section_menu parent=site_root calling_page=self %}
                {% endblock %}
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

**navbar.html (where my default menu lies)**

```
{% load menu_tags static %}

<nav class="navbar navbar-static-top yamm ms-navbar ms-navbar-dark">
    <div class="container container-full">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
                <img src="{% static 'img/logo.svg' %}" alt="Data Quest AG">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                {% block menu %}
                    {% get_first_level as site_root %}
                    {% top_menu parent=site_root calling_page=self %}
                {% endblock %}
            </ul>
        </div>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="sb-toggle-left btn-navbar-menu">
            <i class="zmdi zmdi-menu"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</nav>
```